# Easy Import Photos (from MTP device, such as Android phone) on Windows 10 and Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, import, mtp

The goal is simple: Import photos - easily - on Windows 10 or Windows 11.

It worked flawlessly on Windows 7 via the autorun pop-up. But on Windows 10, I open Photos, click Import, and it just gets stuck at Import. It will show 16 out of 100 for example, and just never finishes. The computer, the SSD is not doing any work according to Task Manager.

So I am looking for a third-party program that provides me with an easy way to import Pictures/Videos from MTP devices (smartphone, digital camera, etc.)

Is there any software that could do this?

**As requested - step-by-step, this is how it gets stuck:**

1. Open Microsoft's Photos app on Windows 10 or 11 (which ships with the OS)
2. There is an Import button on the top-right corner of the window. Press it.
3. **If** you have an MTP device connected, such as an Android phone, or a digital camera, it will let you import the images from the device.
4. In theory. Not so much in reality.
5. You may get the freeze right here where it tries to scan for images. It will never finish, it just tries to load the thumbnails but it will never present you with the actual thumbnails because it just freezes up.
6. But, you may make it one step further, where you get the actual thumbnails. You may think, this might actually work. Do not be fooled. This is Microsoft and Windows after all.
7. Click Import and it will show some arbitrary number, such as "16" out of whatever many pictures you have. This is where you get stuck.

And that is the process.

**It must be the OS! DISM, SFC, sprinkle holy water on it, cast spells!**

Well, no: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/photos-app-freezes-upon-import-photo-importing/ffc01ac1-ad9c-440d-aee2-7faf946caf80

It is just another broken piece of hot garbage, just like Snipping Tool that could freeze upon ya in the entirety of Windows 10's release cycle. It even freezes up today, with the latest updates.

**Must be a broken phone!!**

It is an A32 Samsung with the latest updates. But feel free to check out that thread above. Just a casual number of 469 replies - all from people using apparently the oh so wrong phone.

**So it never worked?!**

On the contrary. It always worked on Windows 7. The autorun dialog popped up, and upon the user clicking "Import images", the program imported all the pictures without a hitch, a hiccup, or a flaw. It was flawless. Was. Oh and as a bonus, it also worked on XP and Vista.

**Why not just copy it by hand!?!**

First, the phone appears, great. The user has to somehow figure this out. To open Explorer, navigate to the phone. Good. Now they have an Internal Storage and the SD card. Okay? But wait, there is more. They click on Internal Storage and they are presented with a thousand folders. I suppose knowing Android layout is just common knowledge so shame on them. But wait, even if they know what "DCIM" is, the pictures can be all over the place, because Android vendors follow standards like Linux distributions do. (They do not.) Point is, each app likes to have their own little folder for their pictures.

But okay, let's say the user figures all this much and gets to the pictures. How do they copy easily only the newer pictures to their PC? Let's say to Photos? Drag the whole folder? Overwrite all on the PC?

Do you, dear reader, see what kind of inane task all this is? And I'm not angry at Microsoft - only - I am also angry at the Android vendors for stopping the development of their software suits while only making 9 billion dollars through sales each week.

**Bonus point:** Since it's not like a pendrive or disk drive, you can't just write a program or a batch script for this.

Comment: I really don't understand the need to "import" things from the phone.  I plug in USB, I set the phone for "file sharing", I open the phone and go to DCIM.  I copy the files.  Is this android or apple?

Comment: Please list each step you take, specifically and completely. Also, is the issue happening on a different computer?